# For a continuous distribution, can I replace the mean by the median in two sample z-test?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, median, robust, z-test

For a continuous distribution, can I replace the mean by the median in two sample z-test?  Assuming that populations are normally distributed.  I feel like they can because both median and sample mean converge to the population mean (unknown).

Comment: Median of what?

Comment: You could do an approximate inefficient test based on differences in medians if you can estimate the standard error of that difference.   You can't use ordinary standard deviations in the calculation.  But if you want a general, powerful, robust test consider a nonparametric one.

Comment: You can, provided you make an adjustment, because the variance of the sample median is not given by the usual formulas. Using the median suggests you are concerned about the potential influence of outliers, in which case you must estimate the standard error of the median in a robust manner, too.

Comment: I think you'll get more useful answers if you give us some context about WHY you want to substitute median for mean and WHY you are using a z test rather than a. test.